# Archive menu isn't clickable in XCode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to submit a new version for an app, but can't do it from Xcode (Menu > Product > Archive). The `Archive` menu is simply gray, I can not click it.

Do anybody knows how can I solve this problem? I could do it without any problems in XCode 5.

Comment: select the device instead of simulators

Comment: ohh, what a dummy mistake. thanks @AliAB. Please add it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select iOS device (or any other connected device) instead of simulators device.

[image]